# How to make a priority queue use a variable from custom a class (Ascending/descending)

Tags: c++, priority-queue

I am having trouble with using the `priority_queue` in C++, I have a vector of priority queues, the priority queues contains several `Person` objects. Now I would like for the `priority_queue` to prioritize the `Person` objects based on their age. So I have something like this:

```
class Person
{
public:
  string name;
  int height;
  int age;
};

std::vector<std::priority_queue<Person*>> Persons;
```

How do I make sure that whenever a person is added to one of the priority queues, that they are prioritized based on their age? And how would I do it in ascending/descending order?

Comment: Have you tried consulting suitable [reference documentation of `std::priority_queue`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue)? Have you seen the template parameter `Compare`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually don't need the additional vector which wraps your priority_queue as the priority_queue itself has 2 additional default arguments: 
(first one is the type, in your case Person*), second one is the container type and the third one is the compare predicate.
below you can see using a lambda function as a compare predicate for your priority queue.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <queue>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Person
{
public:
    string name;
    int height;
    int age;

    Person(string n, int h, int a): name(n), height(h), age(a) {}
};


ostream& operator<<(ostream &cout, const Person* p) {
    return cout << p->name << " height=" << p->height << " age=" << p->age << " ";
}

int main()
{
    auto cmp = [](const Person* pl, const Person* pr) {
        return (pl->age < pr->age);
    };

    priority_queue<Person*, vector<Person*>, decltype(cmp)> persons(cmp);

    persons.push(new Person("a", 100, 10));
    persons.push(new Person("b", 120, 20));
    persons.push(new Person("c", 110, 15));

    while (!persons.empty()) {
        cout << persons.top() << endl;
        persons.pop();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a predicate as third parameter to detect sort order, declare two predicates for your `Person*`

```
struct AscendingPersonPredicate
{
    bool operator() ( Person* p1, Person* p2) const
    {
        return p1->age < p2->age;
    }
};

struct DescendingPersonPredicate
{
    bool operator() ( Person* p1, Person* p2) const
    {
        return p1->age > p2->age;
    }
};
```

Then declare your vector as:

```
std::priority_queue<Person*, vector<Person*>, AscendingPersonPredicate> Persons;
```

or

```
std::priority_queue<Person*, vector<Person*>, DescendingPersonPredicate> Persons;
```

Answer (score 0):

`std::priority_queue` has an interface for what you require. It takes three template parameters:

```
template<
    class T,
    class Container = std::vector<T>,
    class Compare = std::less<typename Container::value_type>
> class priority_queue;
```

The third one is what you need to change to handle the comparison of elements.

```
// make a functor to do the comparisons
struct comparator
{
    bool operator()(Person* lhs, Person* rhs) const {
        // sort by age
        return lhs->age < rhs->age; // switch the sign for reverse order
    }
};

// have a type alias for convenience (typedef is fine too)
using pqueue = std::priority_queue<Person*, std::vector<Person*>, comparator>;

int main() 
{
    std::vector<pqueue> persons; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement like this :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;



class Person
{
public:
    string name;
    int height;
    int age;

};

struct OrderByAge
{
    bool operator() (Person const &a, Person const &b) { return a.age > b.age; }
};


int main() 
{
    vector<priority_queue<Person, std::vector<Person>,OrderByAge> > personPQVec{ 1 };

    Person p1{ "nitendra",5,39 };
    Person p2{ "bhosle",6,34 };
    Person p3{ "nit",4,33 };


    personPQVec[0].push(p1);
    personPQVec[0].push(p2);
    personPQVec[0].push(p3);


    while (!personPQVec[0].empty()) {

        cout << "Name: " << (personPQVec[0]).top().name << ", age: " << (personPQVec[0]).top().age << endl;
        (personPQVec[0]).pop();
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```